# how to get real-time access to grid data from map generated by gmapping?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to simulate robot exploration in gazebo using gmapping. Now I'm able to generate the map using SLAM and save it using map_server.

I would like to ask how do I **get access to the individual grid data**? for example I need to detect the frontier grids and calculate its distance to the current position of the robot, how do I achieve this in ROS? I suppose it should be a matrix or something similar, any help or suggestion would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227270/how-to-get-real-time-access-to-grid-data-from-map-generated-by-gmapping?/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi!,

I think that the information you are looking for, is published in the topic /map. If you take a look to the gmapping documentation http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping , you will see that gmapping, publish the occupancy grid information, in the format of a message of the type http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html, in the topic /map. So, you should just subscribe to that topic, to get the information you are looking for.

Hope this helps you!

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on 2016-02-24**:
Thanks for your reply. I've checked that out, but the map data there is a 1 dimention data and I could not figure out how to convert it to the actual 2 dimention array. Do you know how to do this?

**Comment by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) on 2016-02-24**:
Hi!, did you look at the content of the OccupancyGrid Message?, following the documentation this message, " represents a 2-D grid map, in which each cell represents the probability of occupancy.". So i think it should be a 2D info. Are you sure you are looking at the correct topic?

**Comment by [az](https://answers.ros.org/users/33491/az/) on 2018-03-01**:
hi,i am having the same issue,occupancy grid does say its 2D but int8[] data is one dimensional which only gives information if the cell if empty or not but i cant seem to find the (x,y) coordinates related to each of the cell.Do i have to do it myself by using loops or some other library maybe?

**Comment by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on 2018-03-05**:
@az As for my case, I implemented my own conversion and it's a easy one:
def convertTo2DArray():
for i in range(map_width):
for j in range(map_heigh)
slam_map[i][j] = raw_map[i + j * map_width]

where the width and height are obtain from map message received from 'map' topic.

**Comment by [az](https://answers.ros.org/users/33491/az/) on 2018-03-10**:
Thanks alot!

**Comment by [tarunuday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30296/tarunuday/) on 2018-03-15**:
Essentially, the grid data is in row-major index format - which means if the width of the row (which you can get from map.info.width) is 1000,

map.data[0] = [0,0]

map.data[356] = [356,0]

map.data[1000]= [0,1]

map.data[72653]=[653,72]

**`map.data[ i ]=[(i%width),(int)(i/width)]`**